# How to use StandardSetController in extension class

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I want to create extension class with StandardSetController.

```
public with sharing class AccountExtCtrl {

  private ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl {get;set;}
  public AccountExtCtrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)        
  {
    ctrl = controller;
  } 

  //todo

}
```

but when i use this extension to visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountExtCtrl">
  <!-- todo -->
</apex:page>
```

always print this:

> common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeApexObjectType cannot be cast to
>   common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexType

Comment: Try specifying your `standardController` as a `standardSetController`, or ensure you have a constructor that accepts a `ApexPages.StandardController`.  the difference between the two is whats creating the error (and an unhelpful one at that)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get this error because you are trying to cast a `StandardController` to a `StandardSetController`. Note that you can define both constructors on one extension, in which case the extension can be used for either markup approach. Note that using a `StandardSetController` allows you to use the page in a `List Button`, whereas using a `StandardController` allows you to use it in a `Detail Button`.

**Works**

```
<apex:page standardController="..." extensions="MyExtension">
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

(or)

```
<apex:page standardController="..." recordSetVar="records" extensions="MyExtension">
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

(or)

```
<apex:page standardController="..." recordSetVar="records" extensions="MyExtension">
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    // overloaded constructor logic
}
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    // overloaded constructor logic
}
```

**Fails**

```
<apex:page standardController="..." extensions="MyExtension">
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

(or)

```
<apex:page standardController="..." recordSetVar="records" extensions="MyExtension">
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: @C.William If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Adrian Larson's answer you can also use StandardSetController without declaring `standardController` or `recordSetVar` in the VF page.

```
<apex:page controller="YouController" >
private ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc;
public YourController(){
    ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
        Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT your query here... ]));
}
```

And then wrapping all the methods of the StandardSetController in your own functions.

```
public void getNext(){
    ssc.next();
}

public void getPrevious(){
    ssc.previous();
}

etc...
```