# How to solve this error Unknown constructor 'MassDelete.MassDelete(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

// Apex Class
//This problem is occurred while I Use extension concept in VisualForce Page it give error Here is Code//

```
public class MassDelete {

    public List<Account>accounts{set;get;}
    public  MassDelete(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        accounts=(List<Account>)controller.getSelected();
         List<String> fields=new List<String>          {'Name','Phone','Industry','Rating'};
           controller.addFields(fields);

    }
    public PageReference Deletee(){
        Database.delete(accounts ,false);
        PageReference p=new PageReference('/001/0');
        return p; 
    }
}

//VisualForce page
<apex:page  standardController="Account" extensions="MassDelete">
    <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Deletee}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
             <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Rating}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, in your extension you are using `StandardSetController`. You have to alter your VF page to use `recordSetVar`. StandardSetController is used for showing records in bulk and in pagination, the VF page iterates over them. The list variable used for iteration is recordSetVar.

```
<apex:page  standardController="Account" extensions="MassDelete" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Deletee}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
             <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Rating}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Src: [What is recordSetVar and where is it used?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97423/what-is-recordsetvar-and-where-is-it-used)

Src : [How to use StandardSetController in extension class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144830/how-to-use-standardsetcontroller-in-extension-class/144831#144831)